# iptables: FORWARD rule not taking effect

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, forwarding

I have a linux box running iptables. Traffic goes through it coming in wlan0 and going out wlan1. I want to allow only specific machines to go through. I tried by MAC, it failed, then I tried by IP and to my surprise it failed too.

For both cases I put the FORWARD policy as DROP

```
$ iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Then I did

```
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m mac --mac-source 76:AB:BF:80:4E:B3 -j ACCEPT
```

When it didn't work I activated log with:

```
$ iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -j LOG
```

kern.log showed that my source MAC address was the MAC of the linux wlan0. Then I tried by IP address:

```
$ iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.10 -j ACCEPT
```

It also failed. I then tried to leave the policy as accept and put the following, to drop everything, after my above rule:

```
$ iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

But it still didn't work as my client had its packet droped. It only works when the policy is ACCEPT (but then there is no filtering). That makes me believe the rule is not matching the traffic. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My complete iptables chains:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MAC 76:AB:BF:80:4E:B3
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.10         anywhere           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: the -A is APPEND which makes it the last rule on the list.  Having no idea what your complete chain looks like we can't tell you where it should go.

Comment: I edited the question with the complete chains. Thank you

Comment: change -J ACCEPT to -J LOG --log-prefix " test MAC match" and see what shows up in dmesg